# does join of ForkJoinPool block the current thread worker?

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

I'm trying to run a number of jobs concurrently using Java's `ForkJoinPool`. The main task (which is already running in the pool) spawns all the jobs and then does a series of joins. I was sure that a task calling `join` would free the thread it is running in, but it seems like it is actually blocked on it, and therefore it is "wasting" the thread, i.e., since the number of threads equals the number of CPU cores, one core will be inactive.

I know that if I run `invokeAll` instead, then the first of the sub-jobs gets to run in the same thread, and indeed this works. However, this seems sub-optimal, because if the first task is actually a very fast one, i have the same problem. One of the threads is blocked waiting on `join`. There are more jobs than threads, so I would rather another one of the jobs gets started.

I can try and bypass all this manually but its not so nice, and it seems like I am redoing what `ForkJoinPool` is supposed to do.
So the question is: Am I understanding `ForkJoinPool` wrong? or if what I'm saying is correct, then is there simple way to utilize the threads more efficiently?

Comment: "but it seems like it is actually blocked on it", how does it seem that way? Are you using `getActiveCount()` and see that there's one less thread active than should be? Include the relevant parts of your code to show how you're using FJP.

Comment: Just because a thread is in a blocked state does not mean that it is sitting on a physical CPU core, preventing it from doing other work. The runtime or OS can/will schedule other threads on the core it was using.

Comment: I see it is blocked by running an example: it forks all the sub-jobs, and I see that the number of active ones is smaller than what I would expect. When I change to invokeAll, the number indeed increases by 1. But still, when the job that is running on the main thread (which is now running the first job), is finished, it doesn't pick up another one, but rather is blocked on the join.

Comment: Indeed, the scheduler will let other stuff run - but there is no other stuff! I want it to start running the rest of the jobs (i have 80 jobs, and the pool is of size 16)

Answer (score 3):

`ForkJoinPool` is designed to prevent you having to think about thread utilization in this way. The 'work stealing' algorithm ensures that each thread is always busy so long as there are tasks in the queue.

Check out these notes for a high-level discussion:
[https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs891f/2018-PDFs/L4-ForkJoinPool-pt3.pdf](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/cs891f/2018-PDFs/L4-ForkJoinPool-pt3.pdf)

To see the ugly details go down the rabbit hole of the `ForkJoinPool#awaitJoin` [source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#l1999).

Roughly, if I'm reading the (very complex) code correctly: When a thread `join`s a sub-task, it attempts to complete that task itself, otherwise if the sub-task's worker queue is non-empty (i.e. it is also depending on other tasks), the joining thread repeatedly attempts to complete one of those tasks, via `ForkJoinPool#tryHelpStealer`, whose Javadoc entry provides some insight:

> Tries to locate and execute tasks for a stealer of the given
> task, or in turn one of its stealers, Traces currentSteal ->
> currentJoin links looking for a thread working on a descendant
> of the given task and with a non-empty queue to steal back and
> execute tasks from. The first call to this method upon a
> waiting join will often entail scanning/search, (which is OK
> because the joiner has nothing better to do), but this method
> leaves hints in workers to speed up subsequent calls. The
> implementation is very branchy to cope with potential
> inconsistencies or loops encountering chains that are stale,
> unknown, or so long that they are likely cyclic.

Notice that `ForkJoinTask` does not extend `Thread`, so 'blocking' of the `join` operation means something different here than usual. It doesn't mean that the underlying thread is in a blocked state, rather it means that the computation of the current task is held up further up the call stack while `join` goes off and attempts to resolve the tree of sub-tasks impeding progress.